# Does Web 8.5 provide detailed information about CM users activities/session?

Tags: core-service, content-manager, web8.5, database

I want to generate a report on individual User’s activities like:

1. Logged-in Information
2. How long they remain connected to system
3. Activities they performed or browsing details

I can pull out the logged in information from IIS logs on 2013 SP1 as we don't have anything OOB, but want to know if SDL Web 8.5 provides this information or introduced any user related information in CM database?

Answer (score 4):

With regards to part 3:

There is some information stored in the Content Manager database. For example, most items (Components, Pages, etc.) store a version history of who updated them, at what time and what changes were made. This does not cover all items (e.g. Structure Groups) though!

Also, the Publish Transactions are stored, so you can see who published what and when.

However, I suspect that you'll need a custom dashboard / tool to report on this information. I recommend that you look at the following question on the Meta site for further inspiration: [Example Tridion Reports](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389/example-tridion-reports)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing new in that area in Web 8.5.